# Problem in VSCode "$gcc" problem matcher to recognize file path in C++ compiler error reports

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have just set my launch.json and tasks.json as the tutorial on the Internet said. But when I pree F5 compile and find some errors, I cannot click the red words "errors" showed in the "Problems". 
[image: Description]

If I click, the information will be:
[image: Description]

Anyone can help me?

---

task.json

```
{
    // https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: looks like the problem matcher you use has an error, it concats the path of the file twice. You have a simple syntax error in your cpp source around line 50-51

Comment: Yes, that's true, I can see the error but I can't click them and jump to the error lines to correct them( that's annoying, which paramater in the problem matcher is wrong?

Comment: What is your `task.json` - Edit your answer

Comment: Here ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S9mNw624sS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `"$gcc"` problem matcher defined in `ms-vscode.cpptools-0.XX.0` extension.

It is the same problem matcher as mentioned in the [Task documentation about problem matchers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher).

This matcher uses relative paths. But MinGW with g++ v8 uses absolute file paths in the error when the source file is supplied with absolute file path in the `args` property of the task.

Solution is to modify the `"$gcc"` problem matcher and use absolute file path.

```
      "problemMatcher": {
        "base": "$gcc",
        "fileLocation": "absolute"
      },
```