# Visual Studio Code doesn't populate the Problems tab when I try to debug multiple files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

HeIIo. This is my first post on Stackoverflow.

I like computer programming and after some experience with Python and VBA I'm trying to learn the C.
Since I took up with it I use Visual Studio Code for training in order to learn how to use modern programming tools at the same time.

I've never had any problem until now, but at the moment I want to compile multiple files.

When I try to compile a file with a warning the terminal shows it

```
Executing task: C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -Wall -W -pedantic -ansi -std=c99 -O -g 'd:\OneDrive\Programmi\C\Kim_N_King-Programmazione_in_C\Capitolo 19\stackADT\stackclient.c' 'd:\OneDrive\Programmi\C\Kim_N_King-Programmazione_in_C\Capitolo 19\stackADT\stackADT3.c' -o 'd:\OneDrive\Programmi\C\Kim_N_King-Programmazione_in_C\Capitolo 19\stackADT\stackADT.exe'

d:\OneDrive\Programmi\C\Kim_N_King-Programmazione_in_C\Capitolo 19\stackADT\stackADT3.c: In function 'is_full':
d:\OneDrive\Programmi\C\Kim_N_King-Programmazione_in_C\Capitolo 19\stackADT\stackADT3.c:41:20: warning: unused parameter 's' [-Wunused-parameter]
 bool is_full(Stack s) {
              ~~~~~~^
```

but in the "Problems" tab it's not shown
[(see the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emvxS.png).

In every other folder where there is only a .c file to compile it works flawlessly.

The followings are my jsons file from which you can easily understand my VSC configuration and platform.

Thank you for reading.

**c_cpp_properties.json:**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**launch.json:**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\stackADT.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-Wall",
                "-W",
                "-pedantic",
                "-ansi",
                "-std=c99",
                "-O",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "${fileDirname}\\stackADT3.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\stackADT.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: you don't have a **Problem Matcher** defined in your `task.json`. Try the `"$gcc"` predefined matcher but change it to use absolute paths https://stackoverflow.com/a/61314277/9938317

Comment: why have you hard coded the .c and .exe files in the launch and task file: use variables for current file

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you compile with flag "-Wall". It means that all warnings will be considered errors. You should use this variable.

for instance

```
(void*) &s;
```